# Changing blending of contour label to multiply

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour, overlay, layouts

I would like to label my maps like these in QGIS (image created using Photoshop):
Image of contour label being shown on the contour lines with with white halo and then the colored raster layer above it is blended with multiply

[image: example1]

Instead, it shows like this. White halos on the contour remains even if the contours are not visible, can not be blended with the layers above

[image: example2]

Is there any way to create the first map in QGIS?

Comment: Try to avoid using `a Buffer` for labels. Check this [QGIS Docs | Buffer tab](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#buffer-tab)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the blend mode of the text buffer in label settings (see below).

[image]

Multiply works best if the buffer colour is a dark colour. However, that won't achieve what you have in your screenshot (see results below):

[image]

---

Instead, you should use the new [Mask setting in QGIS 3.12](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-selective-masking) to mask out the line symbology in a buffer around the text.

First, in your label settings, disable any text buffers, and go to the Mask tab. Enable the mask with your desired "buffer" size.

[image]

Next, go to the Mask settings, and check your line symbology as the masked symbol layer (sorry it's not very clear in this screenshot). Then, select the label mask as the mask source (you will only see this option if you set it up in label settings in the previous step)

[image]

Now your line symbology will be masked out around the text per your request.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awesome!